# print out 2-d array with this format

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on finding words in 2 dimensional array, and I got the searching works ( vertical, horizontal, and diagonal )

I just wasn't able to print the found words in this specific format. like it prints the words where actually it find it in the 2D array.
I hope my idea was clear

the code reads Charters from a file.txt and save them into 2d array.
and we search for a word in this array.

and try to find them in the same order they are in. 
I attached an example

```
   Puzzle          word file       Output
n o h t y p s      ruby
m i a r y c c      cave          c
l l e k s a h                      a
r u b y v m e                r u b y v
e h h e l l m                          e
p c j n i c e
r e e k b i p
```

this is the code...

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class WordPuzzle {

    // to print..
    private Set<Point> wordPoints = new HashSet<>();




    public Set<String> findWords(char[][] puzzle, String[] inputWords) {
        Set<String> foundWords = new HashSet<String>();
        int minimumWordLength = findMinimumWordLength(inputWords);
        Set<String> possibleWords = findPossibleWords(puzzle, minimumWordLength);
        for(String word : inputWords) {
            for(String possibleWord : possibleWords) {
                if(possibleWord.contains(word) || possibleWord.contains(new StringBuffer(word).reverse())) {
                    foundWords.add(word);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }       
        return foundWords;
    }

    private int findMinimumWordLength(String[] inputWords) {
        int minimumLength = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(String word : inputWords) {
            if(word.length() < minimumLength)
                minimumLength = word.length();
        }
        return minimumLength;
    }

    private Set<String> findPossibleWords(char[][] puzzle, int minimumWordLength) {
        Set<String> possibleWords = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        int dimension = puzzle.length; //Assuming puzzle is square
        if(dimension >= minimumWordLength) {
            /* Every row in the puzzle is added as a possible word holder */
            for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
                if(puzzle[i].length >= minimumWordLength) {
                    possibleWords.add(new String(puzzle[i]));
                }
            }
            /* Every column in the puzzle is added as a possible word holder */
            for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
                StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer();
                for(int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
                    temp = temp.append(puzzle[j][i]);
                }
                possibleWords.add(new String(temp));
            }
            /* Adding principle diagonal word holders */
            StringBuffer temp1 = new StringBuffer();
            StringBuffer temp2 = new StringBuffer();
            for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
                temp1 = temp1.append(puzzle[i][i]);
                temp2 = temp2.append(puzzle[i][dimension - i - 1]);
            }
            possibleWords.add(new String(temp1));
            possibleWords.add(new String(temp2));
            /* Adding non-principle diagonal word holders */
            for(int i = 1; i < dimension - minimumWordLength; i++) {
                temp1 = new StringBuffer();
                temp2 = new StringBuffer();
                StringBuffer temp3 = new StringBuffer();
                StringBuffer temp4 = new StringBuffer();
                for(int j = i, k = 0; j < dimension && k < dimension; j++, k++) {
                    temp1 = temp1.append(puzzle[j][k]);
                    temp2 = temp2.append(puzzle[k][j]);
                    temp3 = temp3.append(puzzle[dimension - j - 1][k]);
                    temp4 = temp4.append(puzzle[dimension - k - 1][j]);
                }
                possibleWords.add(new String(temp1));
                possibleWords.add(new String(temp2));
                possibleWords.add(new String(temp3));
                possibleWords.add(new String(temp4));
            }
        }
        return possibleWords;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        WordPuzzle program = new WordPuzzle();
        ////////////////////////////////////////// if you want to copy the word file, copy here. //////
     // allocate the file..
     File inFile = new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\workspace\\DS600\\src\\Puzzle.txt");    
     // scan the file..
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile); 
    // create an array of type char
        char[][] puzzleInput = new char[50][50];    
    //assign every letter in the char array
        for(int i=0; i < 50; i++) {
            puzzleInput[i] = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
        }

        scanner.close();
      ////////////////////////// end the copy file here. //////////////////////////

        String[] InputWords = {"ONE", "TWO","THREE","POLAND"};      
        Set<String> wordsFound = program.findWords(puzzleInput, InputWords);


        // PRINT OUT... ONLY
        for (int y = 0; y < puzzleInput.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < puzzleInput[y].length; x++) {

                // HOW TO PRINT IT .. ??

            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    /*    
        for(String word : wordsFound) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
        */

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a working code I've written when solving a similar problem at a coding competition. It finds the words inside a 2-D char array and prints them out with coordinates. Hoping that this will be helpful...

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] crossword = new char[][]{
                {'f', 'd', 'e', 'r', 'l', 'k'},
                {'u', 's', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'o'},
                {'l', 'n', 'g', 'r', 'o', 'v'},
                {'m', 'l', 'p', 'r', 'r', 'h'},
                {'p', 'o', 'e', 'e', 'j', 'j'}
        };
        List<Word> allWords = detectAllWords(crossword, "home", "same");
        for(Word word : allWords) {
            System.out.println(word.toString());
        }
        /*
        Expected result:
        home - (5, 3) - (2, 0)
        same - (1, 1) - (4, 1)
        */
    }

    public static List<Word> detectAllWords(char[][] crossword, String... words) {

        List<Word> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
        int[][] searchDirections = new int[][] {
                {0, 1},
                {1, 1},
                {1, 0},
                {1, -1},
                {0, -1},
                {-1, -1},
                {-1, 0},
                {-1, 1},
        };
        for (String word : words) nextWord:{
            for (int i = 0; i < crossword.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < crossword[i].length; j++) {
                    if (word.charAt(0) == crossword[i][j]) {
                        for (int directions = 0; directions < searchDirections.length; directions++) {
                            int tmp_i = i, tmp_j = j, wordPos = 1;
                            while (wordPos < word.length()) {
                                tmp_i += searchDirections[directions][0];
                                tmp_j += searchDirections[directions][1];
                                if (tmp_i < 0 || tmp_i >= crossword.length || tmp_j < 0 || tmp_j >= crossword[tmp_i].length)
                                    break;
                                if (word.charAt(wordPos) != crossword[tmp_i][tmp_j])
                                    break;
                                else if (wordPos == word.length() - 1) {
                                    Word tWord = new Word(word);
                                    tWord.setStartPoint(j, i);
                                    tWord.setEndPoint(tmp_j, tmp_i);
                                    wordList.add(tWord);
                                    break nextWord;
                                }
                                wordPos++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return wordList;
    }

    public static class Word {
        private String text;
        private int startX;
        private int startY;
        private int endX;
        private int endY;

        public Word(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public void setStartPoint(int i, int j) {
            startX = i;
            startY = j;
        }

        public void setEndPoint(int i, int j) {
            endX = i;
            endY = j;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s - (%d, %d) - (%d, %d)", text, startX, startY, endX, endY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to print it out in the same format as it is in the array  :) and let me know if u can.. it's very challenging

Comment: Not really, if you've noticed - in my code I print out the starting and finishing coordinates for each word. Hence, you can just recreate your array and print in the same format. That's pretty simple, try. If you don't succeed I'll show you.

Comment: Alright, I did that for you, added as a separate answer - it works just as intended. rep would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have a second array that's just empty but the same dimensions as the first, and every time you find a word in the first array, you add all the letters from the word to the second array in the order of the first. So, for example, once you look through the first array and find "ruby" in some position, add "ruby" in the same position to the second array. That way, you're adding all the words you find to an empty array, resulting in an array that contains only the words you found in the exact same positions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my original answer, here is the full code of what you exactly need. Notice the print2DArray(...) static method which does all the work of printing the found words in the very same positions as they were inside the original array:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] crossword = new char[][]{
                {'f', 'd', 'e', 'r', 'l', 'k'},
                {'u', 's', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'o'},
                {'l', 'n', 'g', 'r', 'o', 'v'},
                {'m', 'l', 'p', 'r', 'r', 'h'},
                {'p', 'o', 'e', 'e', 'j', 'j'}
        };
        List<Word> allWords = detectAllWords(crossword, "home", "same");
        // Print the results with starting and ending coordinates:
        for(Word word : allWords) {
            System.out.println(word.toString());
        }
        // Print the results as they are inside the original array
        print2DArray(allWords, crossword);
    }

    public static void print2DArray(List<Word> words, char[][] array) {

        char[][] toPrint = new char[array.length][array[0].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                toPrint[i][j] = '#';
            }
        }

        for(Word word : words) {

            int vectorX = word.endX - word.startX;
            int vectorY = word.endY - word.startY;

            if(vectorX > 0) {
                vectorX = 1;
            } else if(vectorX < 0) {
                vectorX = -1;
            }

            if(vectorY > 0) {
                vectorY = 1;
            } else if(vectorY < 0) {
                vectorY = -1;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < word.text.length(); i++) {
                toPrint[word.startY + (i * vectorY)][word.startX + (i * vectorX)] = word.text.charAt(i);
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < toPrint.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < toPrint[i].length; j++) {
                if(toPrint[i][j] == '#') {
                    if(j == toPrint[i].length -1) {
                        System.out.println("  ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("  ");
                    }
                } else {
                    if(j == toPrint[i].length -1) {
                        System.out.println(" " + toPrint[i][j]);
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(" " + toPrint[i][j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Word> detectAllWords(char[][] crossword, String... words) {

        List<Word> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
        int[][] searchDirections = new int[][]{
                {0, 1},
                {1, 1},
                {1, 0},
                {1, -1},
                {0, -1},
                {-1, -1},
                {-1, 0},
                {-1, 1},
        };
        for (String word : words)
            nextWord:{
                for (int i = 0; i < crossword.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < crossword[i].length; j++) {
                        if (word.charAt(0) == crossword[i][j]) {
                            for (int directions = 0; directions < searchDirections.length; directions++) {
                                int tmp_i = i, tmp_j = j, wordPos = 1;
                                while (wordPos < word.length()) {
                                    tmp_i += searchDirections[directions][0];
                                    tmp_j += searchDirections[directions][1];
                                    if (tmp_i < 0 || tmp_i >= crossword.length || tmp_j < 0 || tmp_j >= crossword[tmp_i].length)
                                        break;
                                    if (word.charAt(wordPos) != crossword[tmp_i][tmp_j])
                                        break;
                                    else if (wordPos == word.length() - 1) {
                                        Word tWord = new Word(word);
                                        tWord.setStartPoint(j, i);
                                        tWord.setEndPoint(tmp_j, tmp_i);
                                        wordList.add(tWord);
                                        break nextWord;
                                    }
                                    wordPos++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        return wordList;
    }

    public static class Word {
        private String text;
        private int startX;
        private int startY;
        private int endX;
        private int endY;

        public Word(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public void setStartPoint(int i, int j) {
            startX = i;
            startY = j;
        }

        public void setEndPoint(int i, int j) {
            endX = i;
            endY = j;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s - (%d, %d) - (%d, %d)", text, startX, startY, endX, endY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: very impressive man, I looked at ur code, it was too complex, how did u do it? u must be a genius lol

Comment: Lol, it's not as hard as it seems. I'm glad it did help you though.